# Kafka schema registry - Broker: Broker failed to validate record

Tags: go, apache-kafka, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

I'm verifying the schema using the Kafka schema registry. The problem is that even though I put in the correct schema, I still get the error `Broker: Broker failed to verify record.`

confluent.value.schema.validation is set to true so that value's schema can be examined at the current broker level.

The schema i set and the data i send are as follows.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "description": "Sample schema to help you get started.",
  "properties": {
    "test": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "title": "schema_test",
  "type": "object"
}
```

```
{"test": "test1"}
```

Additionally, I am sending data using go and the code for the data is as follows.

```golang
// main

func main() {
    kafka.ProduceData("schema_test", []byte(`{"test": "test1"}`))
}
```

```golang
// kafka
func ProduceData(topic string, data []byte) {

    conf := ReadConfig()

    p, err := kafka.NewProducer(&conf)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to create producer: %s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    defer p.Close()

    // Go-routine to handle message delivery reports and
    // possibly other event types (errors, stats, etc)
    go func() {
        for e := range p.Events() {
            switch ev := e.(type) {
            case *kafka.Message:
                if ev.TopicPartition.Error != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("Failed to deliver message: %v\n", ev.TopicPartition)
                } else {
                    fmt.Printf("Produced event to topic %s: key = %-10s value = %s\n",
                        *ev.TopicPartition.Topic, string(ev.Key), string(ev.Value))
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    p.Produce(&kafka.Message{
        TopicPartition: kafka.TopicPartition{Topic: &topic, Partition: kafka.PartitionAny},
        Value:          data,
    }, nil)

    // Wait for all messages to be delivered
    p.Flush(15 * 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding of how data is actually verified by the broker. It's working as expected. You need a *Schema ID*. You're just sending plain JSON on the topic with no ID. The schema on the registry doesn't really matter, only its ID does.

From docs

> enables the broker to verify that data produced to a Kafka topic **is using a valid schema ID in Schema Registry**

More specifically, the schema you've added to the registry is just one of many "versions" that could exist on a subject (such as `topic-value`). Each version has a unique ID. The validation doesn't just use the latest version; that ID is encoded client side.

See Confluent example of producing with a JSON Schema (which itself should do record validation).

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/examples/json_producer_example/json_producer_example.go

The broker side validation is just to prevent incorrectly serialized data, or "poison pills", as you're effectively doing now.

Comment: I completly misunderstanding about schema registry. thank you!!